# How to view all archived items in sitecore 6

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

i'm using Sitecore 6.5. I have 2 users that have the exact same role, say user A and user B.

When i archived an item with user A, i can see the archived item in the user A archive manager but not in user B.

How do i give access to the users so that they can see all archived items from all users without setting them as admin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The archive application is using the `Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.GetEntries` method to retrieve the archived items from the database and it filters the items by the current user (using the `ArchivedBy` field) unless the current user is an administrator.

So to allow everyone to see every archived item you would have to create your own implementation of the `GetEntries(User user, int pageIndex, int pageSize, ID archivalId)` method. Simplest way might be to create a new Advanced System Reporter report and then override the `SqlArchive.GetEntries` method and pass in `null` as the user as that has the same effect as an administrator.