# Sitecore Get Archived items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I need to get an item from the "Archive" to see whether a particular item is in the archive (if its archived, notify the user its archived).

I have seen in an example in StackOverflow [Get Items from Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557458/how-to-view-all-archived-items-in-sitecore-6)
uses `Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.GetEntries` method. But I don't get the `GetEntries` method under `Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive`.

I am using Sitecore 6.6. Is this method not available in 6.6? Is there any other way I can query the Sitecore Archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the archives from the current database use:

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"]
Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["recyclebin"]
```

There are 3 methods that should be sufficient to get anything from the archives:

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"].GetArchivalId(itemId)
Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"].GetEntries(archivalId)
Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"].GetEntriesForUser(user, pageIndex, pageSize)
```

Comment: What's the archivalId in GetEntries? How do you get that?

Comment: I think you get get that using `Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["archive"].GetArchivalId(itemId)`